# Maximum block of bits of 1 in a 32 bits array Verilog

Tags: arrays, module, verilog, bit, maxlength

I am a beginner in Verilog and I have this task.

max_pass circuit filters an array of 32 bits such that the blocks of bits 1 of maximum length remain on position and everything else becomes 0.

A block/set is consisted of minimum 2 bits of 1.

The circuit has to be combinational and the interface of the max_pass module is:

```
input  [31:0] din  ;
output [31:0] dout ;
```

The circuit has no memory. Output immediately sees any changes in input.

It is recommended to use modular and hierarchical design.

**Examples**

```
Example 1   
input:      01011100111111111111011100101010
output:     00000000111111111111000000000000
The maximum length of a block is 12.

Example 2   
input:      00100111111001001011111100101101
output:     00000111111000000011111100000000
Two blocks of maximum length of 6.

Example 3   
input:      11011011011011011011011011011011
output:     11011011011011011011011011011011
Eleven blocks of maximum length of 2.
```

Comment: As this is not a code writing service it would be good if you could show what you have tried. A start would be to write the interface in Verilog.

Comment: The circuit let pass only the maximum block of 1 bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of work in progress: to find the maxim block size present, and calculate the location vector.

`block_is[i]` represents when there is a block size of i or greater.

Identify max block size and OR the shifted number of location vectors together to create the output.

```
module tb;
  reg [15:0] seq;
  reg [15:0] loc_vector;
  reg [15:0] block_detect;



  initial begin
    #1ps seq = 16'b0101_1100_0110_1110;
    #10ns;
    $displayb(loc_vector);
    $displayb(block_detect);
    $finish();
  end

  reg [15:0] block_is = 16'b0;
  reg  [3:0] max_block;  //integer max of block_is 

  always @* begin
    block_is[0] = ~|seq; //All 0
    block_is[1] = |seq;  //Atleast 1
    block_is[2] = 
    (seq[15:14] == 2'b11) |
    (seq[14:13] == 2'b11) |
    (seq[13:12] == 2'b11) |
    (seq[12:11] == 2'b11) |
    (seq[11:10] == 2'b11) |
    (seq[10: 9] == 2'b11) |
    (seq[ 9: 8] == 2'b11) |
    (seq[ 8: 7] == 2'b11) |
    (seq[ 7: 6] == 2'b11) |
    (seq[ 6: 5] == 2'b11) |
    (seq[ 5: 4] == 2'b11) |
    (seq[ 4: 3] == 2'b11) |
    (seq[ 3: 2] == 2'b11) |
    (seq[ 2: 1] == 2'b11) |
    (seq[ 1: 0] == 2'b11) ; 

    block_is[3] =
    (seq[15:13] == 3'b111) |
    (seq[14:12] == 3'b111) |
    (seq[13:11] == 3'b111) |
    (seq[12:10] == 3'b111) |
    (seq[11: 9] == 3'b111) |
    (seq[10: 8] == 3'b111) |
    (seq[ 9: 7] == 3'b111) |
    (seq[ 8: 6] == 3'b111) |
    (seq[ 7: 5] == 3'b111) |
    (seq[ 6: 4] == 3'b111) |
    (seq[ 5: 3] == 3'b111) |
    (seq[ 4: 2] == 3'b111) |
    (seq[ 3: 1] == 3'b111) |
    (seq[ 2: 0] == 3'b111) ; 

    //etc complete for block_is 4 to 14

    block_is[15] = &seq; //AND reduction all 1's

    loc_vector = seq;
    if (block_is[1]) begin
      //always do first shift if have block of 1
      loc_vector = loc_vector & (seq << 1);
    end
    if (block_is[2]) begin
      //do second shift if have at least a block of 2
      loc_vector = loc_vector & (seq << 2);
    end

    //Find max Block Size
    for (int i=0; i<16; i=i+1) begin
      if (block_is[i]) begin
        max_block = i;
      end
    end

    block_detect = loc_vector;
    //Turn Location Vectors in to max_blocks
    for (int i=2; i<16; i=i+1) begin
      if ( max_block >=i )
        block_detect = block_detect | (loc_vector >> (i-1));
    end
  end

endmodule
```

Which outputs:

```
0001000000001000
0001110000001110
```

Comment: Good. Now having location vector how am I supposed to generate output?

Comment: Added final part to answer to generate the output required.

Answer (score 0):

@Morgan

I've thought of a solution. Using a MUX-DMUX circuit I can compare 2 numbers of 2 bits, let's say M,N and the function return 1 if M>N (it can be modified to return 1 if M=N=11 also ). So, I have a 32 bits array and start comparing using this algorithm.
Now, I`m not sure how to find the longest block.

[2 numbers M=ab N=cd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fU5dI.png)
[image]

[MUX-DMUX circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4jdr.png)
[image]

Comment: I think initially a for loop is required to identify the largest block. I also do not think the problem should be solved combinatorially. If the 32 bit value could be clocked in serially (bit-by-bit) then a state machine could analyse it to identify the largest block.

Comment: @Morgan I have found a solution but I need help with implementation

Comment: Another solution or the one mentioned above?

Comment: @Morgan another solution

Comment: It would be good if you could update the question, with your proposed solution showing what you can.

Comment: @Morgan still can`t find an answer any idea ? Remember combinatorially not sequentially

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a 16 bit example.

Input:         010**1 11**00 0110 **111**0    We have 2 max blocks of 3 bits.

Location vector:  0001 0000 0000 1000

Output should look like this : 000**1 11**00 0000 **111**0

Location vector contains a 1 bit that is aligned with the left-most 1 bit of the max block.
Location vector is obtained by shifting input to the left by 1 and then apply AND operation between the two arrays, repeating the process until we get the vector.

Example:

```
         Input:   0101 1100 0110 1110
    Shift left:   1011 1000 1101 1100   
 AND operation:   0001 1000 0100 1100
Shift left again: 0011 0000 1001 1000
AND with input:   0001 0000 0000 1000  --> Location vector
```

Output has a 1 bit in the same position as location vector(in this case position 3 and 12, counting from right to left).

**For the 1 in position 3:**
The output in the previous position (position 2) is a 1 if and only if the output in position 3 is a 1 and the input vector has a 1 in position 2.
The output in the position 1 is a 1 if and only if the output in position 2 is a 1 and the input vector has a 1 in position 1.

**For the 1 in position 12:**
The output in the previous position (position 11) is a 1 if and only if the output in position 12 is a 1 and the input vector has a 1 in position 11.
The output in the position 10 is a 1 if and only if the output in position 11 is a 1 and the input vector has a 1 in position 10.

Do you see how this will cascade the max block bits to the output? In essence, the bit in the location vector serves as a trigger and the bits in the input vector serve to sustain a pulse of 1 bits to the output as long as they last.

The problem is that I'm not sure how to implement this behavioral code and if this is a good solution.

I am waiting for your opinion and ideas.Thanks!

Comment: As it is combinatorial, you will have to compute all shifts (16) and ignore the ones that are not based on the largest size block size.

Comment: @Morgan I don't get it.

Comment: You shift 2 times in this example, what makes you stop shifting? How do you know how many times to shift?

Comment: Shifting maxLenthofBlock - 1 @Morgan

Comment: Exactly, how do you know the maxim block size present? Working on an answer for this bit

Comment: This is the problem. Cant find maximum size